# XMLHttpRequest using FileEntry Object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to access a file on the server but the only way of dynamically tracking the user's request is through FileEntry Objects.

Is it possible to use a FileEntry object with an XMLHttpRequest in order to obtain the file for parsing?
I am open to any other suggestions of accessing an excel file in a given directory.

```
this.getDirectoryEntry(function(result, directory, name) {
            var success;
            var results;
            chosenDirectory = directory;
            self.getAllFileEntries(directory, function(success, results) {
                self.fileEntryCallbackHandler(results, directory.name);
            });
        });
```

Get Directory allows them to select a directory to parse for excel sheets. The function call back gives you a boolean if it was successful, a directoryEntry, and the name of the directory.

Comment: Are you trying to access a file on the user's local file system using the File API? I don't understand the question. Maybe if you showed some code.

Comment: Yes I am parsing through a directory chosen by the user whether it is on their drive or on their network somewhere